# An interesting point?

Tags: riddle, word

I'm a length of hard wood
Hooped with iron at each end
Used for making a block
Or a case to defend

My sound is like silence:
Dumb, irrelevant am I
Talk about me forever
For I point to the sky

*Hint 1*

> I am a single, four-letter word.

*Hint 2*

> The first clue is archaic.

*Hint 3*

> The title is a clue.

*Hint 4*

> But for the difference in sound between a cat's and a cow's, the "sound" clue is homophonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> moot. Means "irrelevant", sounds like "mute".

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's an

> Idea

- It's a four letter word that matches the title (an interesting point).
- It can be used to block other ones or give you something to defend.
- Its sound is quiet (especially while forming one)
- Dumb ones are useless/irrelevant
- They're constantly talked about
- Point to the sky... Either the "light bulb" effect or something pithy about it "taking flight"

I can't figure out the wood/iron clue, but I assume I'm missing something obscure, since the hint specifically calls it archaic.

Comment: close - you are thinking along the right lines :)